# How to use ggplot to make a heat map based on the points' own value?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggmap

Suppose I have a data frame of a spatial grid with 3 columns:

```
> pressureData
       lon   lat  pressure
1   -113.8 -21.2 1000.0000
2   -111.2 -21.2 1000.0000
3   -108.8 -21.2 1000.0000
4    -93.8 -21.2 1000.0000
5    -91.2 -21.2 1000.0000
6    -76.2 -21.2  997.2222
7    -73.8 -21.2  999.9306
8    -71.2 -21.2  990.2778
9    -68.8 -21.2  809.5139
10   -66.2 -21.2  673.2639
```

I want to plot them on a map by using ggplot() and ggmap(). So far I have something like this:
[image]

The code I used is:

```
myMap = ggmap(mylocation) + 
        geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, show_guide = TRUE, colour = pressure), 
        data = pressureData, alpha = .5, size = 5, shape = 15)  + 
        scale_color_gradient(low = "beige", high="blue")
```

The map looks okay and I can roughly tell which region has lower pressure, but I want my result to look like a heat map.

-----------------------update--------------------

```
myMap = ggplot(pressureData) +
        aes(x = lon, y = lat, z = pressure, fill = pressure) +
        geom_tile() + 
        geom_contour(color = "white", alpha = 0.8) 
myMap
```

[image]

I revised my code and obtained the above result, but when I want to add my map under the contour plot, I got an error:

```
myMap = ggplot(pressureData) +
        aes(x = lon, y = lat, z = pressure, fill = pressure) +
        geom_tile() + 
        geom_contour(color = "white", alpha = 0.8) +
        ggmap(mylocation)

Error in p + o : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("+.gg", "Ops.data.frame") for "+"
```

I suspect that the size difference of the two graphs cause this problem, but how do I fix it?

Comment: what does "look like a heat map" mean? do you mean you want a filled contour map that's based on the pressure value? also, can you link to a data file? you can use something like `geom_tile(aes(x, y, z = z, fill = z)) + stat_contour()` if that's what you're going for. also the new `viridis` package provides a superb color palette for this.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I am looking for. And by the hint you had given, I was able to produce a result that is similar to my expectation, but I encountered a new problem when I try to add the contour my map, as you will see in the update of this post

Comment: start with `ggmap` (it returns a ggplot2 object) then look at [this](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/gg-add.html) for how to "switch" base data frames which will then let you use new aesthetics and add the tile & contour layers.